# EEG signals does not give the negative point in microcontroller

Tags: msp430, eeg

I made my own EEG circuit, and have some problems. In the beginning, I did not come across this situation but, suddenly, I started to get these outputs, and I could not find the reason. When I upload my EEG ADC signals to MSP430 it was working like this:

[image]

I did not change anything, but now it is giving these signals:

[image]

I touched a little bit to my electrodes it became like this but, it came to the same situation:

[image]

I have tried to put some DC bias and coupling capacitors, but it did not work, maybe I did not make it properly.

[I made it as described in this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxmPJbDdjKo&t=336s)

[image]

In my circuit, I used INA121, instrumentation stage, HPF for 0.5 Hz, and LPF for 200 Hz. They are inverting amplifiers. Maybe I could not make proper DC biases or another problem. I am getting 2 inputs as AC signals. Can you advise any solution, DC bias design also can be?

Comment: Welcome! Please post a full schematic. You you using you MCU’s internal ADC? Are you aware it can’t sample negative voltages?

Comment: Do you mean "upload to" or "sample with"??  Many microcontrollers can't sample negative numbers, and many EEG circuits you'll find therefore add an offset to the signal.

Comment: @ScottSeidman it does not need to be in the negative area. the output was like the first plot. between some ADC values like a sinus signal, if I need offset. how can I add?